# Colorir um campo duma coluna segundo parametros

Tags: php, html, phpmyadmin

Tenho uma tabela com 5 colunas e dois registros. Um dos campos no registro é um numero (notaQualif), necessito que o campo em que está inserido fique pintado de verde caso este seja maior que 75 e pintado de vermelho caso seja menor que 75.

Todos os dados estão guardados numa base de dados criada em phpmyadmin, sendo assim necessário que, quando o utilizador introduz dados, seja verificado a notaQualif e fique logo pintado de verde ou vermelho.

Deixo [aqui](https://www.dropbox.com/s/wa89z65235744s4/campos.txt?dl=0) o código feito até agora que contempla a tabela com os dados.

```
<head><title>Ver registos</title></head>
```

```
<?php
    LigarBDfater(); //connect to the database


    // get results from database
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM qualificacao") or die(mysql_error());


    // display data in table
    echo "<p><b>View All</b> | <a href='view-paginated.php?page=1'>View Paginated</a></p>";
    echo "<table border='1' cellpadding='10'>";
    echo "<tr><th>ID Qualifica&ccedil;&atilde;o</th> <th>ID Fornecedor</th> <th>Nome Funcionario</th> <th>Nota Qualifica&ccedil;&atilde;o</th> <th>Data Qualifica&ccedil;&atilde;o</th></tr>";


    // loop through results of database query, displaying them in the table
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){

        // echo out the contents of each row into a table
        echo "<tr>";
        echo '<td>' . $row['id_qualific'] . '</td>';
        echo '<td>' . $row['id_fornecedor'] . '</td>';
        echo '<td>' . $row['nomeFuncionario'] . '</td>';
        echo '<td>' . $row['notaQualif'] . '</td>';
        echo '<td>' . $row['dataQualif'] . '</td>';
        echo "</tr>";
    }

    // close table>
    echo "</table>";
?>

<p align="left"><a href="novo_qualificacao.php">Adicionar um novo registo</a></p>
```

Comment: Posta o código aqui, ao menos uma parte, para eu poder te ajudar.

Comment: Tem uma hiperligação no "Deixo aqui" que redireciona para o dropbox com o código. Conseguiu visualizar ?

Comment: Como sua pergunta vai ficar registrada aqui, é uma boa prática (se não for uma regra), colar o código no corpo da pergunta.

Comment: Okok, editei e agora está com código

Comment: @crispypedro_ com código ficou bem simples, verifica se a resposta te serve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Faça a seguinte Alteração no teu PHP:

```
if($row['notaQualif'] > 75) echo '<td class="bgVerde">' . $row['notaQualif'] . '</td>';
else echo '<td class="bgVermelho">' . $row['notaQualif'] . '</td>';
```

E nos estilos aplique:

```
td.bgVerde {
  background-color: #07CC36;
  color: #FFF;
}
td.bgVermelho {
  background-color: #c12536;
  color: #FFF;
}
```